# Facebook login problem

Tags: 13.10, facebook

Running ubuntu 13.10 and have Facebook in online accounts.  When I access this in online accounts and click on facebook, nothing happens.  Can an icon be placed on start page where I can log on to facebook or is there another way.  Thanks...

Comment: Is the issue only present on google-chrome? To check, try the same things in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow to steps given in this link to download and install Facebook App on ubuntu:
http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/fb-messenger-and-facebook-applications.html.

After installing the Ubuntu Desktop Facebook Application, you will find it in the Unity dash Applications.

For creating a shortcut on desktop, Go to the folder /usr/share/applications and find the facebook app.
Then right click on it and copy.
Now open up the Desktop folder.
Right click and then select paste.

The facebook app will be on your desktop !!